# $.ajax and accented characters issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using this ajax code to send data to server:

```
$.ajax({
    data: postData,
    type: method,
    url: url,
    timeout: 20000,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,err){alert("Error returned from ajax call "+err);},
    success: function(data,status,jqXHR){
        // process response...
    }
});
```

`postData` is a query string with many values while `method` is `GET` or `POST`

The problem is that, when I send a query string that contains a value like `Älypuhelimen lisävarusteet`, the result in database is `�lypuhelimen lis�varusteet`

The database connection collation is utf-8, and this works fine when I do not use ajax to post and save to database... It is definitely ajax that messes up the encoding...

I have also tried using encodeURIComponent() function on the data, and it becomes `%C4lypuhelimen%20lis%E4varusteet` if I use it... same goes for escape() function...

any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Sorry guys! The problem was with the post data itself... the postData was being parsed by a function which used escape() to url escape all query variables... using encodeURIComponent() instead of escape() fixed the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for information and to help others that might fall in the same situation...

The problem was with the postData itself... it was parsed such that every post variable was applied with escape()... Using encodeURIComponent() instead of escape() worked!

**Summary:**
Donot use escape() function to url-escape query components... use encodeURIComponent() instead...

Answer (score 1):

You should try jQuery Base64 encode.

JavaScript:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.base64.min.js"></script>
<script>
    enctext = $.base64.encode("yourtext");
    //your ajax code goes here.
</script>
```

PHP :

```
<?php
   $org_text = base64_decode($_POST['your_variable']);
?>
```

jQuery Base64 plugin.

download from here.

https://github.com/carlo/jquery-base64

Comment: This means I will have to base64_encode all the POST variables in JS and base64_decode all of them in PHP... which is not quite practical because the same PHP is used for ajax and normal both calls... Also base64_encode sometimes corrupts data...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the column in the database to utf16_bin Collation

> Post you php database connection code.

Comment: The column in database is utf8 which is same as the data sent... also worth noting that if called without ajax... same js/form/php code saves data perfectly in database... therefore it is not an issue with database collation or connection collation...

Comment: Check sure your php file is in utf-8 and the connection to the database is with the utf-8 charset. The database is saved correctly?

Comment: Yes I have made sure that php file sends utf-8 header and database and its connection collation are both in utf-8... infact as I said before... if I do not use ajax.. the string saves perfectly correct in database and even shows perfect on my php generated html output page... which confirms that something is messed during ajax call...